# Comparison of JsonNode in javers

Tags: javers

**Person Class**

```
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   int id;
   Address address;

   public int getId() {
    return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
   } 
   public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
   }
   public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
   }

   Person(int id, Address address){
    this.id=id;
    this.address=address;
   }
  }
```

**Address Class**

```
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  String state;
  String city;
  CodeInfo codeInfo;
  public CodeInfo getCodeInfo() {
            return codeInfo;
  }
  public void setCodeInfo(CodeInfo codeInfo) {
            this.codeInfo = codeInfo;
  }

  public String getState() {
       return state;
  }
  public void setState(String state) {
      this.state = state;
  }
  public String getCity() {
      return city;
  }
  public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
  }
  public Address(String state, String city,CodeInfo codeInfo) {
      this.state = state;
      this.city = city;
      this.codeInfo = codeInfo;
  }
 }
```

**CodeInfo class**

```
 public class CodeInfo implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      String prop;
  public String getProp() {
    return prop;
  }

  public void setProp(String prop) {
     this.prop = prop;
  }
  public CodeInfo(String prop) {
    this.prop=prop;
  }
 }
```

**JaversNewClass**

```
public class JaversNewClass {
     private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Diff diff =JaversInstance.getInstance().compare(
               MAPPER.valueToTree(new Person(1,new Address("Delhi",null,new 
                                           CodeInfo(null)))),
               MAPPER.valueToTree(new Person(2,new Address("Noida","SEZ",new 
                                           CodeInfo("abc"))))
              );
           System.out.println(diff.toString());
     }
 }
```

**Diff:**

```
* new object: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode/#_children/address/_children/codeInfo/_children/prop
* changes on com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode/ :
  - '_children/address/_children/city._value' property with value 'SEZ' added
  - '_children/address/_children/codeInfo._children' map changes :
    'prop' -> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode/#_children/address/_children/city' changed to 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode/#_children/address/_children/codeInfo/_children/prop'
  - '_children/address/_children/state._value' value changed from 'Delhi' to 'Noida'
  - '_children/id._value' value changed from '1' to '2'
```

In the current scenario I have two JsonNodes which I am comparing through javers.

So firstly i need to know is it possible to compare the json nodes in this way.

Secondly, I need to know why i am getting the new object and irrelevant map change instead of the value change.

However it is able to detect the address changes properly. This case is detected when nested object is changed from null..

Comment: What i expect is '_children/address/_children/codeInfo/_children/prop._value' property with value 'abc' added

Comment: https://github.com/divikrckr/javers